# Opening project for 2013 in 2012 Visual Studio for MVC gives error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am getting an error when trying to open a MVC project in Visual Studio 2012. My team is running on 2013 that have been working on it, and I am waiting to be upgraded to 2013, but am trying to get some work done until then. When I open the project, it says it is missing some required Web components needed to run in Visual Studio. "ASP.NET Web pages with Razor 3.0.0.0". So I tried to do a NuGet install for AspNetMVC and did not work. I can open the project and what not, but the features such as adding a new View or Controller are not there. Do I have to wait until I am upgraded to 2013, or am I missing something?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. There is an update I didn't find until just now for 2013 tools to work in 2012. So trying it out.

Comment: You should be able to install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages` version 3.0.0 from Nuget?

Comment: This package is already installed according to VS when I look at NuGet package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Had to re-install WebPages package with NuGet manager. I have no idea why it was jacked, but it was and fixed the problem.  Thanks @levelnis.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to update my NuGet package manager to the newest version in order to download the missing / corrupted package.